# Can anyone help and tell me why do i get a null value in the function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Heres the Code

This is the Script

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#done_edit').click(function(){

    var name= document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    alert(name);
   });
});
```

This is for the form

```
<form id="passedit" class="submit">
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text"  name="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="done_edit" >DONE<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></button>
```

Comment: I don't see the element which has id `first_name`

Comment: Also use `.value` in order to find out the value.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var name= document.getElementById('first_name');
You should have an element wich has the ID as "firstname".
For example,`

> `<input type="text" id="first_name" value="Type your text here"/>`
>   Then you'll get the output as an object.

If you rewrite the mentioned line as follows,

> `var name= document.getElementById('first_name').value;`
>   You'll get "Type your text here" in your alert box.
>   **ie: Change the attribute name to id in your textbox.**

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have an element with an Id set to first_name

you should have something like

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have in the alert the value of the element.

**HTML**

```
<form id="passedit" class="submit">
<label>ID Number:</label><input id="first_name" type="text" 
 name="id_number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo 
 $row['name'];?>" />
<button type=
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#done_edit').click(function(){
      var name= document.getElementById('first_name').value;
      alert(name);
   });
 });
```